# Вынести docker контейнеры из localhost

Tags: php, nginx, docker, сеть

Подскажите, как я могу настроить сеть контейнеров, чтобы я мог к ним подключаться по определенному ip, а не по локалхосту (речь о подключении из браузера). Расчет на то, что у меня будет несколько проектов, у каждого из них будет свой контейнер php, nginx и mysql. Пока один проект, docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
        php:
            build:
                args:
                    uname: ${PHP_UNAME}
                    uid: ${PHP_UID}
                    gid: ${PHP_GID}
                context: ./docker/php
            container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_php
            image: ${PROJECT_NAME}_php
            restart: unless-stopped
            volumes:
                - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
                - ./:/var/www/${PROJECT_NAME}
            environment:
                PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=${XDEBUG_STORM_SERVER_NAME}
                PROJECT_NAME: ${PROJECT_NAME}
            networks:
                main_network:
                    ipv4_address: ${PHP_HOST}
            depends_on:
                - db
        db:
            image: mysql
            restart: unless-stopped
            container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_db
            environment:
                MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
                MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
                MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
                MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            ports:
                - ${DB_PORT}:3306
            volumes:
                - ./services/database/dump:/var/lib/mysql
            networks:
                main_network:
                    ipv4_address: ${DB_HOST}
    
        nginx:
            image: nginx
            restart: unless-stopped
            container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx
            ports:
                - ${NGINX_LOCAL_PORT}:80
            volumes:
                - ./:/var/www/${PROJECT_NAME}
                - ./docker/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            networks:
                main_network:
                    ipv4_address: ${NGINX_HOST}
            depends_on:
                - php                                                                
    networks:
        main_network:
            driver: bridge
            name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_main_network
            ipam:
                driver: default
                config:
                    -   subnet: ${SUBNET_IP}/${SUBNET_MASK}
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports

Comment: А в чем проблема у вас сейчас? По логике сайт должен быть доступен по вашему IP адресу в интернете, если файрволл не блокирует его.